# how to find & replace a file path listed in a file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, replace, xml

I have a file content as shown below. If a line has ".idt" word, then I need to check if there is a file path preceding it (eg: /bin/dir/test/abcdef.idt). If yes, then remove the file path and keep only the actual file name (eg: abcdef.idt). The idt file need not always be mentioned with absolute path; it can just be the filename alone. There can be only one idt file mentioned in a line (between one < file>..< /file> tag).
This needs to be done for all the files in a directory.

In the below example, see the 3 lines having emptest1.idt, emptest2.idt & emptest3.idt

### Sample Input file content (xml file):

```
<Application Name="empBnf" ServiceType="SOAP" BitMode="32" Path="/test/bin"/>
<FileList>
    <File>/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/emptest1.idt</File>
    <File>emptest2.idt</File>
    <File>
          /test/src/repos/emp.deploy/emptest3.idt
     </File>
    <File>/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/emptest.wsdl</File>
</FileList>
<Service Qualifier="http://www.mytest.com/test/empbnf" Name="/test/src/repos/empBnf" XManagement="Container">
    <Operation>Operation</Operation>
</Service>
```

### The output has to be:

```
<Application Name="empBnf" ServiceType="SOAP" BitMode="32" Path="/test/bin"/>
<FileList>
    <File>emptest1.idt</File>
    <File>emptest2.idt</File>
    <File>
          emptest3.idt
     </File>
    <File>/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/emptest.wsdl</File>
</FileList>
<Service Qualifier="http://www.mytest.com/test/empbnf" Name="/test/src/repos/empBnf" XManagement="Container">
    <Operation>Operation</Operation>
</Service>
```

Comment: (1) Will the file paths always be absolute pathnames?  (2) Can there be multiple filenames on the same line?  (3) Can you ever have `</File>…<File>/some/path/emptest2.idt` on the same line?  (4) What have you tried?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thank You, G-Man!! Per your suggestion, I have provided the information in the question. I am new to linux shell script; so came through sed command by going through google but none of mine worked... sed -n,  sed-s.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
sed -i -E -e 's/(\/.*\/)(.*\.idt)/\2/' file_list
```

This performs an in-place (`-i`) replacement of all `/..../filename.idt` filepaths with `filename.idt` ("all" as in: the first occurrence on each line of a certain file). If there is no absolute path preceding the filename, the regex does not match, and nothing happens. The `file_list` can be replaced with an `*.xml` or the like at your command prompt. You may want to try running the command without the `-i` option first, to see the output before writing it to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the XML is well formed, the following will remove the string `/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/` from the values of each `File` node that contains that string and the string `.idt` using XMLStarlet (or rather, it leaves the bit of the value that occurs after the path):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//File[contains(., "/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/") and contains(., ".idt")]' \
              -x 'substring-after(., "/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/")' file.xml
```

Adding a `root` node to your example document and running the above command generates

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Application Name="empBnf" ServiceType="SOAP" BitMode="32" Path="/test/bin"/>
  <FileList>
    <File>emptest1.idt</File>
    <File>emptest2.idt</File>
    <File>emptest3.idt
     </File>
    <File>/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/emptest.wsdl</File>
  </FileList>
  <Service Qualifier="http://www.mytest.com/test/empbnf" Name="/test/src/repos/empBnf" XManagement="Container">
    <Operation>Operation</Operation>
  </Service>
</root>
```

It would be even neater if the following worked:

```
xmlstrlet ed -u '//File[contains(., ".idt")]' \
             -x 'replace(.,".*/","")' file.xml
```

... but XMLStarlet (on my system) doesn't seem to want to know about the `replace()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
I Have used below method

command: sed '/idt/s/\/test.*emp.deploy\///g' file
```

output

```
sed '/idt/s/\/test.*emp.deploy\///g' file1
<Application Name="empBnf" ServiceType="SOAP" BitMode="32" Path="/test/bin"/>
<FileList>
    <File>emptest1.idt</File>
    <File>emptest2.idt</File>
    <File>
          emptest3.idt
     </File>
    <File>/test/src/repos/emp.deploy/emptest.wsdl</File>
</FileList>
<Service Qualifier="http://www.mytest.com/test/empbnf" Name="/test/src/repos/empBnf" XManagement="Container">
    <Operation>Operation</Operation>
</Service>
```

Comment: I'd recommend a more-general replacement, instead of requiring "test.*emp.deploy", as the OP said "`if there is a file path preceding it (eg: /bin/dir/test/abcdef.idt). If yes, then remove the file path`" -- I wouldn't assume that *every* path matches "test.*emp.deploy"